# Test for distribution equality

Tags: hypothesis-testing, seasonality, kolmogorov-smirnov-test, iid, two-sample

This question touches Kolmogorov-Smirnov testing, but asks actually something different.

Consider *independent* random variables $X_1, \dots, X_n$. I want to test the following hypothesis:

$$
H_0: X_i\ are\ all\ iid. 
$$

In other words, if $X_i\sim F_i$, I want to test if all $F_i=F_j=F$ where $F$ is some (common) distribution, or there exist two random variables such that $X_i\overset{D}{\neq}X_j$. Problem is that we have only one realization of each $X_i$ (obviously).

One possible area where this question arises is the following: let $A\subset \{1, \dots, n\}$. Consider $X_i\sim N(0, h(i))$, where $h(i)=1$ for $i\in A$, $h(i)=10$ for $i\notin A$ . Then, we can see that $H_0$ does hold iff $A$ is an empty set. How to test it though?

One trivial possibility is to divide the sample into two parts and use classical Kolmogorov Smirnov test. However, we do not know how to divide this sample. We can try first and last half- if $A$ is not kinda symetric this should work. What if it is? We can try other partition and other partition... but is there a better way?

Other possibility for the origin of the question: Let $X_i\sim Exp(log(i+100))$. $H_0$ does not hold. How to test it (without knowing the generating process)?

You can imagine dataset like this: $1.1, 1.3, 1.6, 1.5, 2, 2.1, 2.5, 2.4, 2.9, 3.5, 3.4, 5, 5.1, 5.5, 5.7, 5.2, 5.9$. Here, I would definitely say that $H_0$ is not valid since data does not seem to be iid- larger index $i$ larger mean. I would test it by KS-test between $S_1=\{1.1, 1.3, 1.6, 1.5, 2, 2.1, 2.5\}, S_2=\{2.4, 2.9, 3.5, 3.4, 5, 5.1, 5.5, 5.7, 5.2, 5.9\}$.

Comment: Is $F$ specified or not?  Why is it obvious you have only one realization of each $X_i$?  How could you possibly hope to test the *independence* half of the *iid* criterion in such a case?? What does "$N(0,h(i))$" mean?  (Normal distribution of mean $0$ and sd or variance or precision of $h(i)$?)

Comment: Why exactly do you want to test if the samples are i.i.d.? As you noticed, if they are not i.i.d., you have only one realization for each variable so cannot use this to conclude about it's distribution.

Comment: @whuber: 1- F is not specified  2- It is obvious from the structure of the problem. If its not then we don't understand each other  3- we assume independence, we want to test distribution equality 4-$N(a,b)$ means a gaussian distribution with mean $a$ and variance $b$, and $h(i):\mathbb{N}\to \mathbb{R}^{+}$.

Comment: @Tim-  For example, I would like to see if it is a mixture of two samples or if it is one sample.

Comment: It is not obvious from the structure.  Indeed, since $F$ is not specified, this problem has no solution.   In your example, the empirical distribution $F$ is *perfectly* consistent with your null hypothesis (and is the Maximum Likelihood estimate of $F,$ too).

Comment: You mean the first example with $h(i)$? Well, $F_i\neq F_j$ for $i\in A, j\notin A$ since $F_i$ has smaller variance than $F_j$. Hence, $H_0$ is not true since data are not iid but they have heteroscedastic variance. Does it answer your understanding, or I feel that the misunderstanding lies in something else though

Comment: I am referring to the fully general problem: a useful test doesn't exist, because literally any dataset will be consistent with the null hypothesis.